# Track payment id from button press to database

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Elements to collect payment for an event registration.

I want to store the registration info in my database if payment succeeds or fails so people can pay offline and not lose all the info they have typed in.

I can't see how to get hold of the payment and/or intent ID to store it and then use it later to match up with a webhook call to mark the row as paid.

Comment: this questions needs implementation details, please provide some code for us to better understand where to start looking

Answer (score 0):

This is a general approach but a simple implementation would be:

1. Create a PaymentIntent [1]
2. Save the PaymentIntent ID in your DB alongside the order
3. Collect payment information and authentication (SCA) from the customer
4. Listen on a webhook endpoint [2] tor `payment_intent.succeeded` Events (or failed for that matter)
5. Use the PaymentIntent ID from the payload of this Event to lookup the DB record for the order and mark your order as paid/unpaid etc.

Generally speaking this is outlined in this guide [3], alongside using webhooks to react on Events [4].

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web-create-payment-intent

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/handling-payment-events#create-webhook

[3] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

[4] https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks